# Unresolved external LNK 1120

Tags: c++, external, lnk

http://pastebin.com/Q8Z2deVK

Its a PE file.

I am getting LNK 1120 and LNK 2019.

I googled both errors and it seems that there are a whole bunch of reasons for that error.

LNK 1120 occurs in the same cpp file that my code is pasted in.

LNK 2019 occurs in MSVCRTD.lib (crtexew.obj)

The problme is: I dont have that file. I never created a file like that.

Looking at my code i dont understand how there is anything wrong with it.

I didnt declare any functions that are not defined.

This is how the rest of my project looks like.

This is what i included inside of stdafx.h : http://pastebin.com/VLa7LBx2

The reason i am unable to solve this issue is because the file/symbol that my error refers to doesnt exist. I checked the path and search throughout my whole external dependencie folder. There is not a single file/symbol or function with any of the names.

Comment: Googled "msvcrtd.lib(crtexew.obj) error lnk2019". [First link found](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/14e85604-6929-4707-a22e-8cdf596926a6/msvcrtdlibcrtexewobj-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-winmain16-referenced-in?forum=vclanguage). As for 1120, not nearly enough information provided to help you. Recommend more googling.

Comment: Thank you A LOT man. After 3 hours i finally fixed it. Thank you a lot <3